# Drawable on Android 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

My app works fine in anything before 4.2 but when using 4.2 my drawable hexagons aren't showing. I have a custom class that extends Drawable.

Custom class:

https://gist.github.com/hanleyhansen/8a6bea78017d219a34ef

I then added 2 classes namely this:

https://gist.github.com/hanleyhansen/5deadaebea36e23b0579

This is my full custom class now:

https://gist.github.com/hanleyhansen/32788d63c672cf394e4e

So with that my hexagons show up but they are grey?!?!

This is how I'm drawing my hexagons:

https://gist.github.com/hanleyhansen/d7e5bb9654d97994dfdf

[image: Grey Hexagons]

What's the deal with Android 4.2.2 and Drawable? Any idea why now the colors are not being applied to the hexagons and I'm just getting this greyscale? Would you recommend a different solution as opposed to my added classes?

Comment: could you please post the bare minimal project that shows your problem? maybe just an activity that shows a single hexagon, which works on all versions besides 4.2 ? that would make it easier for us to test it out and check why it occurs...

Comment: @androiddeveloper The easiest way to reproduce it would be using this: https://badgerati.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/drawable-polygon/ which is where I got my custom class from.

Comment: do they have a sample project? i could test the project on my 4.2 device if you wish.

Comment: @androiddeveloper sure. can you join the Android chat room so I can send you a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up replacing the HexagonDrawable class with my own implementation of a HexagonShape which extends shape. This works in 4.2 and in the previous versions as expected. Hope this helps someone.